# Modify launch screen storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

i've added a launch screen storyboard in my project. The storyboard contains a UIView with a UIImageView. The UIImageView shows a .png that i download from a server, and this image could be different every day.
I noticed that iOS cache the images created from the storyboard, but when i start the app with a different image, it shows the older one, and not the one i've downloaded.
The solution should be to change the storyboard to tell the OS that the splash is changed and it could generate new images.
But i don't able to tell the OS the storyboard is changed and it show always the same image.
I've tried to change the structure of the view controller adding some views.

Comment: you cant add or modify the launch screen in storybaord, you should implement custom launch screen to achieve what you need.

Comment: I'm using a storyboard with setting enabled "use as launch screen". I use this storyboard only for the launch screen.

Comment: I think it's a cache problem. Does the image URL change? If not try setting your request's  cache policy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData

Comment: You can't create a dynamic launch screen that changes every time the user runs the app. It doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

The launch screen interface is supposed to be static, it is loaded before your code starts running. So there should be no way to dynamically change the images there.

Maybe someone will find an obscure solution for that, but my guess is that it's not possible right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your project should contain a launch screen .xib file when you create it. You can simply edit the .xib to your liking. There's no need for a new/separate storyboard file.